# What is the name of this molecule? (C₈O₃H₁₃N)

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

@tschoppi

Tried taking a stab at this for me and got this much:

1-(1'-oxoethyl)-2-(something-something ester)-pyrolidine

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UiIrOa2.png]

Comment: @Singh Please do not use markup in the title, compare http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/261/4945

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I managed to see the structure correctly it should be [Methyl 1-acetylprolinate](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.479338.html)

Comment: The natural (S)-isomer.